# Constant CPU speed?

Tags: raspbian, cpu

I'd like to run my Raspberry Pi (3b+) ARM Cortex A53 processor on a **constant** CPU speed, can be the lowest one, doesn't matter, as long as it does not change.

I need this in order to profile some code, which gets harder as the CPU speed constantly varies, CPU goes into power saving idle modes, etc.

Would that be possible?

Comment: arm_freq and arm_min_freq in config.txt